# Filtering condition (JS)

Tags: javascript, filter, conditional-statements

I have filtering script

Here is code

```
 $('#filter').on('click',
    function () {
        heatmap.setMap(null);
        var startValue = $('#startDate').val().split("/");
        $.each(markers, function (i,marker) {
            var getDate = marker.date.match(/\d/g).join('');
            var markerDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));
            var valDate = new Date(startValue[2], startValue[1] - 1, startValue[0]);
           if (markerDate.getDate() === valDate.getDate() && marker.imei === imei) {
                filtered.push(marker);
            } 
        });
        var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(filtered);
        console.log(pointArray);
        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);

    });
```

Now in if I have this

`if (markerDate.getDate() === valDate.getDate() && marker.imei === imei)`

So it will show data only if imei has value.

I need also to show data if I have `markerDate === valDate` and `imei` is null

How I need to write it correctly?

Comment: `If ((condition1a && condition1b) || (condition2a && condition2b))`

Comment: so first condition will be that I have and second will be without `imei`? @Fran

Comment: `if (markerDate.getDate() === valDate.getDate() && (marker.imei === imei || imei === null))`

Comment: And next question is it okay to write so long conditions in `if`? @Fran

Comment: You already spelled your condition out in the question. So just add it using `||` . The question if it is OK to write long `IF` statements is subjective and based on personal preference but if you want you can write it in a method or methods `if(method1() || method2())` for example. You might even want to add those methods to different "classes" if it helps separating concerns and make testing easier etc.. That is completely up to you though.

Comment: Thank's so much @Fran